# path variable for powershell in jenkins bat command

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to execute my powershell script in my Jenkins pipeline. Therefore I use `bat`to call my .ps1 file

```
bat 'powershell "C:\\path\\to\\file\\script.ps1"'
```

Inside the powershell I need to use a specific path. Is there any way to deliver this path with something like:

```
bat 'powershell "C:\\path\\to\\file\\script.ps1"' -var PATH
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to use Pipeline Jobs variables in bat commands

Answer (score 0):

Set up your environment inside the bat step before calling powershell:

```
bat """\
set PATH=....
powershell "C:\\path\\to\\file\\script.ps1"
""";

Inside the block you can reference you're pipeline variables with `${varName}`. So:

def myVar = "somePath"
bat """\
set PATH=%PATH%;${somePath}
powershell "C:\\path\\to\\file\\script.ps1"
""";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use environment variables like `SET "INPT=C:\\path\\to\\file\\script.ps1"` and then use in powershell.

Comment: Consider using [powershell plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PowerShell+Plugin) instead of wrapping command execution inside bat command.

Comment: But is there a way to use the powershell plugin in my pipeline job?